# git describe is not returning the expected tag

Tags: git

I am experimenting with `git describe` as we want to use this in our CI system.
However, I am not getting the expected results and neither the git describe documentation nor googling have helped me understand why.

### The repository

```
git log --oneline --graph

* 9a45651 (HEAD -> main) m c7
*   b7982a9 merged r3
|\  
| * 8c2adbe (tag: v3.0.0) r3 c1
|/  
* 273a50e m c6
*   6014487 merged r2
|\  
| * aa906b8 (tag: v2.0.0) r2 c2
| * 716c189 r2 c1
|/  
* f0e2c71 m c5
* d42bc37 m c4
*   9060516 merged r1
|\  
| * 619d331 (tag: v1.0.0) r1 c2
| * 75f90de r1 c1
* | 372f1fe m c3
|/  
* a27d5e4 m c2
* a66cb53 m c1
```

### Expected result

When running git describe on `main` I expect

```
v3.0.0-x-d???????
```

### Actual result

What I am getting instead is

```
v2.0.0-13-g9a45651
```

### More information

#### git describe --debug

```
# git describe --debug
describe HEAD
No exact match on refs or tags, searching to describe
 annotated         13 v2.0.0
 annotated         13 v1.0.0
 annotated         14 v3.0.0
traversed 15 commits
v2.0.0-13-g9a45651
```

#### amount of commits between tag and HEAD

```
$ git log --oneline v2.0.0..HEAD | wc -l
5

$ git log --oneline v3.0.0..HEAD | wc -l
2
```

#### git version

I have tested `2.36.1` and `2.37.0` both on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` both installed from `# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main`

#### Script to recreate the repository

- https://gist.github.com/twigs/bb0cbe29af55b8141c19d25de47e0eed

Comment: This looks like a bug. I get the same result and it's not sensible. You might want to report this to the Git mailing list (along with the reproducer; my default branch is still `master` so I had to modify it just one tiny bit to rename the default to `main`).

Comment: I don't understand either where the numbers 13 and 14 comes from. If these numbers are correct, then the result is correct; we end up choosing between tag 1 and tag 2, and tag 2 is more recent so it wins. But the numbers themselves seem unnaturally large. How is Git conducting this search? It seems to have something to do with the intervening merge commits. It's as if we go all the way down the first parent chain and then come back up again and start diving into the second parents of each merge commit.

Comment: I just tried it with git version 2.35.1.windows.2 and I got the expected result: `v3.0.0-2-g3d441d5c98`. What version of Git are you using, and what platform are you on? Thanks for creating a script to reproduce the problem, that was really well done.

Comment: But on Debian bullseye with git version 2.30.2 I got the same wrong answer as you.  Maybe a bug that got fixed between these two versions of Git?

Comment: Oh how irritating! It's platform dependent!  Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS git version 2.36.0 and I get the buggy `v2.0.0-13-gdc0464b`. This version of Git is more recent than on my Windows machine where the bug does not happen.

Comment: I have sent the issue to the git mailing list, let's see what we get back from there.

Comment: @joanis My reproduction was on Mac.

Comment: @matt thanks for specifying. So it seems like all but Windows have the bug.

Comment: @circus I just want to echo what joanis said. This is one of the best-asked questions I've ever seen. The preparation was exquisite.

Comment: @matt joanis thanks for the compliment. Now let's hope its good enough to get some feedback from the git mailing list.

Comment: @circus I have found them to be extremely courteous and responsive.

Comment: Elijah from the git mailing list confirmed that it is a defect, no fix in sight atm. https://public-inbox.org/git/CABPp-BH2zuYe87xhjdp5v7M7i+EfEgLHAZgwfzJUAxGk1CFgfA@mail.gmail.com/#t

Comment: This is being discussed in https://public-inbox.org/git/ZQ3SVJWPzAjVbTT0@farprobe/T/#u